# SSRS 2008 R2 Custom Delivery Extension "no longer available"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm having something strange happening here with my new custom delivery extension - I'll come in the day after setting up a new subscription, and the new subscription which uses a custom delivery extension will have the following error: `The delivery extension used by this subscription is no longer available on the report server. To continue, choose a new delivery extension for this subscription.`  I then am able to choose the exact same delivery extension from the drop-down of available extensions.

I checked the `Subscriptions` table in our ReportServer db, and the DeliveryExtension field for that record is now blank.

I'm really confused as to why this would be happening - the server isn't getting rebooted and the VM SSRS is running on wasn't bounced.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**: I was told we're using an instance-based install of SSRS in case that triggers any alarm bells for anyone.

Comment: Is the delivery extension throwing any exception that might be causing the service to decide that it needs to be excluded? I have absolutely no experience dealing with custom extensions. I just thought that SSRS might be trying to protect itself and disabling a badly behaving external component.

Comment: Not according to the logs where I see all the other exceptions that are thrown.  I'll get it working today, and the next morning it's claiming it doesn't exist any longer (despite it being available in the drop-down).

Comment: Are the subscriptions scheduled to run while you're not in? Have you gotten the extension to actually run unattended (not under a debugger)?

Comment: Yes to both.  They're scheduled to start before I get into the office and continue throughout the day.  I can get them working in production once I come in and re-set the delivery extension in the subscription through the Report Manager UI, but something happens overnight which disables them.

Comment: I don't know what kind of monitoring tool you could use to see when the extension is getting disabled. I can guess that you don't want to use the coffee and caffeine method to watch things overnight. :)

Comment: Haha, you got that right!  I suppose I could just set an update trigger to email my SQL Server account whenever an update is made to the Subscriptions table (yes, there will be some noise, but shouldn't be too much...I hope)

Comment: Did you discover anything? Even though I can't really help, I'm curious as to any answer.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing concrete yet.  I've removed the reference to a SharePoint delivery extension that looks to have been throwing an error at one part of the process, and I think I've found a heinous workaround: since I dynamically schedule this job by calling msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule, I can update the Subscriptions table to re-set the DeliveryExtension and InactiveFlags fields before I set the job to run.  I need to get to the bottom of the issue, but this could work short-term.